# Aggregate script ONLY on results of sorted query with filter, not full dataset

Tags: elasticsearch

FYI - elasticsearch @v1.5; npm elasticsearch @4.0.2

For my specific use case, I need to find the five nearest points, around some other point, and calculate the max dist of those five results. For some reason, my query below is returning the max dist of all the filtered data, not the five nearest.

Here's my query thus far:

```
    elasticsearchAPI = Meteor.npmRequire('elasticsearch');
    esClient = new elasticsearchAPI.Client({
        host: 'myHost'
    });

    var esQueryObject = {
        "index": "ma_homes",
        "size": 5,
        "body": {
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "LOCATION": {
                                "lat": 42.5125339,
                                "lon": -71.06748
                            },
                            "distance": "3mi",
                            "optimize_bbox": "memory"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "size": 5,
            "sort": [{
                "_geo_distance": {
                    "LOCATION": {
                        "lat": 42.5125339,
                        "lon": -71.06748
                    },
                    "order": "asc",
                    "unit": "mi",
                    "distance_type": "sloppy_arc"
                }
            }],
            "fields": ["F1_V7_2_F1TOWN"],
            "aggs": {
                "max_dist": {
                    "max": {
                        "script": "doc[\u0027LOCATION\u0027].arcDistanceInMiles(lat,lon)",
                        "params" : {
                            "lat" : 42.5125339,
                            "lon" : -71.06748
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



     try {
        esClient.search(esQueryObject, function(err, res) {
            if ( err ) console.log("err: ", err);
            if ( res ) {
                console.log("res: ", JSON.stringify(res, null, "\t"));
            };
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("search err: ", error);
    };
```

My problem is this returns a max_dist of 2.99, but I can clearly see from the hits that it should only be 0.02268!

Lastly, is there a better way of calculating the max distance? I don't live having to use a script.

See the results, below:

```
I20160729-14:46:08.447(-7)? {
I20160729-14:46:08.447(-7)?     "took": 119,
I20160729-14:46:08.447(-7)?     "timed_out": false,
I20160729-14:46:08.447(-7)?     "_shards": {
I20160729-14:46:08.447(-7)?         "total": 5,
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?         "successful": 5,
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?         "failed": 0
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?     },
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?     "hits": {
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?         "total": 19428,
I20160729-14:46:08.448(-7)?         "max_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.452(-7)?         "hits": [
I20160729-14:46:08.452(-7)?             {
I20160729-14:46:08.452(-7)?                 "_index": "ma_homes",
I20160729-14:46:08.452(-7)?                 "_type": "home",
I20160729-14:46:08.453(-7)?                 "_id": "AVY1KqHN5rKRAKXZHxQf",
I20160729-14:46:08.453(-7)?                 "_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.453(-7)?                 "fields": {
I20160729-14:46:08.453(-7)?                     "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN": [
I20160729-14:46:08.453(-7)?                         "7WHITECIRWAKEFIELDMA"
I20160729-14:46:08.454(-7)?                     ]
I20160729-14:46:08.454(-7)?                 },
I20160729-14:46:08.454(-7)?                 "sort": [
I20160729-14:46:08.454(-7)?                     0.013847018573431258
I20160729-14:46:08.454(-7)?                 ]
I20160729-14:46:08.455(-7)?             },
I20160729-14:46:08.455(-7)?             {
I20160729-14:46:08.455(-7)?                 "_index": "ma_homes",
I20160729-14:46:08.455(-7)?                 "_type": "home",
I20160729-14:46:08.456(-7)?                 "_id": "AVY1Ewoc5rKRAKXZGhMp",
I20160729-14:46:08.456(-7)?                 "_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.456(-7)?                 "fields": {
I20160729-14:46:08.456(-7)?                     "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN": [
I20160729-14:46:08.456(-7)?                         "8WHITECIRWAKEFIELDMA"
I20160729-14:46:08.457(-7)?                     ]
I20160729-14:46:08.457(-7)?                 },
I20160729-14:46:08.457(-7)?                 "sort": [
I20160729-14:46:08.458(-7)?                     0.01675513175670524
I20160729-14:46:08.458(-7)?                 ]
I20160729-14:46:08.458(-7)?             },
I20160729-14:46:08.458(-7)?             {
I20160729-14:46:08.458(-7)?                 "_index": "ma_homes",
I20160729-14:46:08.459(-7)?                 "_type": "home",
I20160729-14:46:08.459(-7)?                 "_id": "AVY1T0cn5rKRAKXZJwC8",
I20160729-14:46:08.459(-7)?                 "_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.459(-7)?                 "fields": {
I20160729-14:46:08.459(-7)?                     "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN": [
I20160729-14:46:08.460(-7)?                         "10WHITECIRWAKEFIELDMA"
I20160729-14:46:08.460(-7)?                     ]
I20160729-14:46:08.460(-7)?                 },
I20160729-14:46:08.460(-7)?                 "sort": [
I20160729-14:46:08.461(-7)?                     0.018417500448048605
I20160729-14:46:08.461(-7)?                 ]
I20160729-14:46:08.463(-7)?             },
I20160729-14:46:08.464(-7)?             {
I20160729-14:46:08.464(-7)?                 "_index": "ma_homes",
I20160729-14:46:08.464(-7)?                 "_type": "home",
I20160729-14:46:08.464(-7)?                 "_id": "AVY1Xb2P5rKRAKXZKhUh",
I20160729-14:46:08.464(-7)?                 "_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.465(-7)?                 "fields": {
I20160729-14:46:08.465(-7)?                     "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN": [
I20160729-14:46:08.465(-7)?                         "11WHITECIRWAKEFIELDMA"
I20160729-14:46:08.465(-7)?                     ]
I20160729-14:46:08.466(-7)?                 },
I20160729-14:46:08.466(-7)?                 "sort": [
I20160729-14:46:08.466(-7)?                     0.018816876925529115
I20160729-14:46:08.467(-7)?                 ]
I20160729-14:46:08.467(-7)?             },
I20160729-14:46:08.467(-7)?             {
I20160729-14:46:08.468(-7)?                 "_index": "ma_homes",
I20160729-14:46:08.468(-7)?                 "_type": "home",
I20160729-14:46:08.468(-7)?                 "_id": "AVY1TNJh5rKRAKXZJnx0",
I20160729-14:46:08.468(-7)?                 "_score": null,
I20160729-14:46:08.469(-7)?                 "fields": {
I20160729-14:46:08.469(-7)?                     "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN": [
I20160729-14:46:08.470(-7)?                         "6WHITECIRWAKEFIELDMA"
I20160729-14:46:08.470(-7)?                     ]
I20160729-14:46:08.470(-7)?                 },
I20160729-14:46:08.471(-7)?                 "sort": [
I20160729-14:46:08.471(-7)?                     0.022680252269458714
I20160729-14:46:08.471(-7)?                 ]
I20160729-14:46:08.471(-7)?             }
I20160729-14:46:08.471(-7)?         ]
I20160729-14:46:08.472(-7)?     },
I20160729-14:46:08.472(-7)?     "aggregations": {
I20160729-14:46:08.472(-7)?         "max_dist": {
I20160729-14:46:08.472(-7)?             "value": 2.999906924854209,
I20160729-14:46:08.473(-7)?             "value_as_string": "2.999906924854209"
I20160729-14:46:08.473(-7)?         }
I20160729-14:46:08.473(-7)?     }
I20160729-14:46:08.474(-7)? }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things wrong here, with the second strongly related to the first:

1. You're assuming that the sorting order has any impact on the aggregation. It doesn't. You may want to have a look at [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide on Scoping Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html).

   - The gist is that the total result of the query, including not-returned-hits are a part of the aggregation's scope. In your exact case, it noted that there were `"total": 19428` documents that matched your search. You just got back the closest 5.
2. You're sorting by ascending order, which means it sorts from least to greatest. This means you're only getting the top 5 *closest* distances, which is what you want, but that doesn't mean that's all the aggregation saw as the true max.

To those points, you need to figure out how to limit the top 5, or just not aggregate at all, which I would suggest is the easiest thing to do here. Simply get the top 5, then grab the last value and you're done getting both answers that you want.

Sorting **is** constrained to what's within 3 miles because of the 3 miles, which is good, but perhaps you can do something better *depending on your needs* by using a faster search `distance_type`:

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "_source": "F1_V7_2_F1TOWN",
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "LOCATION": {
              "lat": 42.5125339,
              "lon": -71.06748
            },
            "distance": "3mi",
            "distance_type": "plane"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "LOCATION": {
          "lat": 42.5125339,
          "lon": -71.06748
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "mi",
        "distance_type": "sloppy_arc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice I don't aggregate, I use `_source` instead of `fields` (`fields` is meant for stored fields, not limiting the source document output), and I am I switched to using `plane` for the filter `distance_type` because it's faster for *short* distances outside of the poles; I doubt too many homes are going to be using distances in the poles. For scoring, I left it as sloppy_arc because it can use a slightly more refined equation after being filtered.

I only get 5 documents back, and of those 5, the last one will be the furthest one away as its score.

As a big side note, [ES 2.2+ increased geo performance significantly](https://www.elastic.co/blog/supercharging-geopoint).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great reply!

I'll definitely read up on scoping, thanks for the link.

I may not have worded it well, but I actually need the max distance, of the fifth, closest point. So, in my example, I was hoping to get 0.02268 in my aggregate.

Also, thanks for letting me know that ES2.2+ has improved performance for geo queries! I'll definitely look into updating! Cheers, and thanks for your help!